# Issue with merge statement

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, data.table

My merge does not seem to be working anymore and I do not why. Below is the code and the sample of the two data sets I am merging

```
head(lookup.table)

   code label
1:  I-2     1
2:  I-3     2
3:  I-4     3
4:  I-5     4
5:  I-6     5
6:  I-7     6  

df 
           Rate
1            S-4
2            S-4
3            S-4
4            S-1
5            S-2
6            S-4
```

Code to reproduce the example

```
library(data.table)

letter=c('I','S','P','D')
start=c(2,1,1,1)
end=c(7,4,3,2)
label=1:15
code.table = data.table(letter,start,end)
code.vector = unlist(apply(code.table,1,function(x) paste(x[1],x[2]:x[3],sep='-')))
lookup.table = data.table(code=code.vector,label=label)

df = data.table(Rate = paste0("S-", c(4,4,4,1,2,4)))
```

Attempt:

```
df$rank = merge(df,lookup.table,by.x="Rate",by.y="code",all.x=TRUE,sort=F)$label
```

Below a sample of the output, and the merge is not producing the expected results. I am expecting the merge to join the lookup.table and df when code=Rate.

```
                 rank           Rate
1                  10            S-4
2                  10            S-4
3                  10            S-3
4                  10            I-5
5                  10            I-5
6                  10            I-6
```

Comment: I should mentioned the merge works as expected when I use a sample data, but it does not when I use the whole data

Comment: `df[lookup.table, on = .(Rate =code), rank := label][]`?

Comment: I guess you should provide an example that illustrates how it fails (providing code to reproduce it in full, not just a picture of part of it).